# How to convert Android stream volume to a value between 0 and 1

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am using a `MediaPlayer` to play sound and I want to take the current stream's volume and set it as the volume for the media player with it `setVolume` method.

The issue is that if I take the value of the volume like this:

```
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

The value I receive is an index of the volume, while the `setSound` method expects a value between 0 and 1.

How do I convert the index to a value between 0 and 1?

Comment: do you know the max possible index? If yes, then divide 1 by max possible index, and multiply by whatever is returned in `audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

Comment: current index / max index. I just need to check if the get max volume returns an index as well and then I'll kick myself for not thinking that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply divide the current volume index by the max volume index of the stream

```
int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

float desiredValue = currentVolume / (float) maxVolume;
```

you can then use that value as you wish (it is beetween 0 and 1)

Comment: I've read that you should scale it logarithmically then why not use:  final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - soundVolume) / 
Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));   ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value between 0-1 by using the code below...

```
private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME + 1 - soundVolume) / 
Math.log(MAX_VOLUME + 1)));
mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
```

Comment: Why not simply soundVolume / MAX_VOLUME?

Comment: Using this muted the volume at max just because the float value was infinity.